# Getting started with Amazon Mechanical Turk for Android

Tags: android, mechanicalturk

I've been working on an app that uses the camera to ake images and I would like to send the image to Amazon's Mechanical turk service and get a description of he image from the service.

I'm totally clueless abou how to do this though. I currently have the java sdk for mturk set up . I cant find any documentation on how I would have to proceed. Will I be able to send the mechanical turk request directly from my app or will I have to do it through a back-end server ? I would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for you to run a server. The Java API "under the hood" connects you to Amazon servers and you are free to just use the API.

You will need to first register with Amazon Web Services and Amazon MTurk and get an Access Key and Secret Access Key (https://portal.aws.amazon.com/gp/aws/securityCredentials) which will enable you to access their API directly.

Here is the Java install link http://aws.amazon.com/code/695 with details.

Also, remember to use the sandbox when testing, not the live site.

Comment: I've already created an account on the requeser site and the aws site and have my access key. I've also installed the sdk. How do I use this within my android app now ? I was able to compile and run the sample program from the terminal, but what should I do if I wanna use it within android ?

Comment: Please refine your question to indicate that you are trying to use MTurk via Android.

Comment: So is not possible to directly do it through Android ?

Comment: I have not worked with MTurk in Android (just Java and .Net on desktop / server). If I was designing such a service I would have my Android app upload the photo to my server. The server in turn would post on MTurk the HIT and monitor for a response (can take anywhere from a minute to never for a HIT to be submitted by a MTurk worker). Once the response is available, the Android app can be updated with a image description that the server stores.